# Relational Table DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**Users Table:**

```
ID    | Name  | UserGroupID  |

1   | John  | 2

2   | Sam    | 11

3   | Kiddo   | 2

4   | Sony   | 3

5   | Jabeen | 1
```

**UsersMachine Table:**

```
ID  | MachineID | EmpID
1  | 1  | 1

2  | 2  | 1

3  | 1  | 2

4  | 2  | 2

5  | 2  | 4

6  | 3  | 5
```

i m looking at single sql to repeat all Users by filtering 
`FROM UserMachine WHERE MachineID = 2` ALSO `FROM Users WHERE UsersGroupID IN (2,11)` with these conditions

I m looking at following reasults:

```
MachineID | UsersName | UsersGroupID 

2     | John  | 2

2    | Sam  | 11
```

Comment: Have you tried a join?

Comment: How do we do? i m weak at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out joins.  They allow us to associate data from two different tables in a single query:

```
SELECT um.MachineId, users.Name, users.UsersGroupID FROM UsersMachine um
INNER JOIN Users users ON users.id = um.EmpID 
WHERE um.MachineID = 2 AND users.UsersGroupID IN (2,11)
```

This is probably the best post (visually) I have seen that help me with joins:
http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/